# Why my UIActionSheet suddenly cutoff at the bottom of the device (iOS 8)?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have some very standard code for UIActionSheet that works well on production.

```
-(void) showGameMenu
{
    UIActionSheet * const activeSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game"
                                                                delegate:self
                                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                       otherButtonTitles:@"New Game", @"Save Game", @"Load Game", @"Email Game", @"Share Position", @"Setup Position", nil];
    [activeSheet setTag:Framework::GameMenuButton];
    [self showActionSheetOnToolbar:activeSheet];
}

-(void) showActionSheetOnToolbar:(UIActionSheet *)sheet
{
    [sheet showFromBarButtonItem:_gameItem animated:YES];
}
```

_gameItem is not nil and is a proper UIBarButtonItem for the "Game" item as shown in the screenshot. The code has been working well on production until recently I tried to compile the same project with iOS 8 (it was compiled with iOS 7).

Suddenly, the menu got cut-off around the bottom edge of the device. Furthermore, there was a transparent black-thing covered about 3/4 of the screen horizontally.

I have no clue why this happens and not sure how to fix it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using auto-layout?

I am not sure but it can be about constraints.I say this because your "Game" and "Flip" buttons look smaller than what you expected.

So I recommend you to delete constraints on your view to your main view and add them again without checking "constrain to margins" via "pin" menu from bottom.

If this is not the case please add what you see in iOS 7.